# Can I use the $string number_format line to superscript my decimals?

Tags: php, string, decimal, superscript

I would like to make the decimals in the following string display as superscript:

```
$string .= number_format(round($value, (int)$decimal_place), (int)$decimal_place, $decimal_point, $thousand_point);
```

I'm not very smart but I have been trying since yesterday using different methods I've found searching stack overflow. Stuff like `."<sup>` or just `"<sup>"` and also `.'<sup>'` and so many other combinations, but nothing works. I either get an error or the price disappears due to the error I introduce into the code because as I said I'm not the sharpest tool in the shed.

Comment: You can use something like `<sup>` for your decimal separator ([here's an example](http://codepad.viper-7.com/98FrrW)), but bear in mind that this will only work in PHP 5.4+.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check out the code I have below, this will format your string, and then use regular expressions to superscript the decimal

```
<?
function superscript_value($value, $prefix = '$') {
    $decimal_place = 2;
    $decimal_point = '.';
    $thousand_point = ',';

    if(round($value, 0) == $value)
        return $prefix . $value;
    else
        return $prefix . preg_replace("/\.(\d*)/", "<sup>.$1</sup>", number_format($value, (int)$decimal_place, $decimal_point, $thousand_point));
}

echo superscript_value(123456.789, '$') . "\n";
// $123,456<sup>.79</sup>
echo superscript_value(10.00, '$') . "\n";
// $10
```

$123,456<sup>.79</sup>

$10

Comment: Thanks that works perfectly. Is it possible to have it **remove double zeros (.00)** from being displayed so that it only displays as even dollars? So instead of `$10.00` it would be `$10`.

Comment: I've updated the code to do as asked, please accept this answer if it truly solves your problem :)

Comment: @BryanMoyles : sorry, Regex is so overkill, besides the delimiter is very predictable. So -1 for preg_replace() instead of explode() ! (will remove it though if you update your code accordingly)

Answer (score -1):

You should use HTML formatting for that:

```
$i = 42;
$string .= "<sup>".$i."</sup>";
```

It will produce something like <sup>42</sup>.